# got error when reading data from big query table

Tags: python, tensorflow-datasets

I'm following the [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/io/tutorials/bigquery#load_census_data_in_tensorflow_dataset_using_bigquery_reader) to read data from big query table. Below is my code.
According to the [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/io/api_docs/python/tfio/bigquery/BigQueryReadSession#parallel_read_rows), the return value of `parallel_read_rows()` is tf.dataset. But `dataset.cardinality().numpy()` returned -2.

```
from tensorflow_io.bigquery import BigQueryClient

 def read_bigquery(table_name):
        bigquery_client = BigQueryClient()
        project, dataset, table = table_name.split(".")
        read_session = bigquery_client.read_session(
            "projects/" + project,
            project,
            table,
            dataset,
            {
                "label": {"output_type": dtypes.int64, "mode": BigQueryClient.FieldMode.NULLABLE},
                "features": {"mode": BigQueryClient.FieldMode.REPEATED, "output_type": dtypes.float32},
            },
            requested_streams=2,
        )
        return read_session.parallel_read_rows()

dataset = read_bigquery(my_table)
```

Also, I got error when reading dataset.

```
returned ds type: <class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.ParallelInterleaveDataset'>
2022-06-30 15:18:47.292204: E tensorflow/core/framework/dataset.cc:577] UNIMPLEMENTED: Cannot compute input sources for dataset of type IO>BigQueryDataset, because the dataset does not implement `InputDatasets`.
2022-06-30 15:18:47.292243: E tensorflow/core/framework/dataset.cc:581] UNIMPLEMENTED: Cannot merge options for dataset of type IO>BigQueryDataset, because the dataset does not implement `InputDatasets`.
2022-06-30 15:18:47.292455: E tensorflow/core/framework/dataset.cc:577] UNIMPLEMENTED: Cannot compute input sources for dataset of type IO>BigQueryDataset, because the dataset does not implement `InputDatasets`.
2022-06-30 15:18:47.292482: E tensorflow/core/framework/dataset.cc:581] UNIMPLEMENTED: Cannot merge options for dataset of type IO>BigQueryDataset, because the dataset does not implement `InputDatasets`.
```

I'm using `tensorflow-io==0.23.1`

Answer (score 0):

`parallel_read_rows()` returns iterator instead of dataset. In order to check value, you can use `list(dataset.take(1).as_numpy_iterator())`.